# what jQuery library does this?

Tags: jquery

I want to be able to have the following UI. When you click on the close button on top, the row below it moves to the top and so on.

[image]

Is there a library for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a library for this. Just bind the click event of the close button to hide the row that it is contained in.

Comment: D'oh.  Ahead of me by 10 seconds.

Comment: then the row below it would slide up? (i.e: animated) mind showing an example?

Comment: Yes, it would, if you used a vertically shrinking effect for the row's hiding. If you want an example, see Blender's answer.

Answer (score 1):

No library, just around four lines of jQuery:

```
$('.item').append('<div class="close">x</div>');

$('.close').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().slideUp();
});
```

And a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/pEVTv/8/

Comment: not sure what's going on with my example, but it seems a bit laggy http://www.screenr.com/JVi

Comment: Can you post your example? Shove the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript into a jsfiddle.net thing